# DB migration generating wrong table design in EF Core (Many-To-Many with AspNetUsers)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to add a list of `Project` entities to my `AspNetUsers` table (AspNetUser, MVC Core project template):

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public IList<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }
}
```

`Add-Migration` adds a `ProjectId` column to my `AspNetUsers` table. That's okay so far.

Adding a list of `Project` to my `ApplicationUser` ends up with an error.

code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Project> Project { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Project.User' of type 'IList<ApplicationUser>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyMappingValidationConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator) 
    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel() 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) 
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.TransientCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.TransientCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) 
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute(CommonOptions commonOptions, String name, String outputDir, String context, String environment, Action`1 reporter)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0() 
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
 Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Project.User' of type 'IList<ApplicationUser>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.
```

What am I missing?! Do I have to use the Fluent API?! I would like to establish a many-to-many relation between AspNetUsers and my Project-Entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many-to-Many relationships require an entity in between.  You need an entity that references both User and Project

```
public class ProjectUser
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

In your existing classes

```
public class Project 
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectUser> ProjectUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<ProjectUser> ProjectUsers { get; set; }
}
```

In your DbContext

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUser>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.UserId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUser>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Project)
            .WithMany(pu => pu.ProjectUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProjectId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUser>()
            .HasOne(u => u.User)
            .WithMany(pu => pu.ProjectUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);
    }
}
```

More information can be found at https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#

Comment: Thanks, just looked at the Roadmap, Many-To-Many with implicit join tables is a high priority feature. Guess I will wait until that works. It's a little bit annoying to do it all manually. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm using EF Core 1.1.0, and I found it has to map the other way, so in your example above:  Entity<Project>().WithMany<ProjectUser>(pu => pu.ProjectUsers).HasOne(p => p.Project)  and then Entity<User>().WithMany<ProjectUser>(pu => pu.ProjectUsers).HasOne(u => u.User)